# Can I use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to restrict an app to iPads and the iPhone 6+?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, iphone-6-plus

I have an app whose UI needs quite a lot of screen space.  At the moment, it's iPad only, but I think it would be OK on the iPhone 6+.  I'd like to make it a universal app but restrict it to iPads and the iPhone 6+.  Is there some combination of device capabilities I can set to achieve this?

Comment: Simon, did you find solution for this? I am also having same problem.

Comment: @PrakashM nothing so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Because iOS 8 supports devices with 3.5" & 4" screens, you can't use the only-support-iOS-x technique.

Also, there isn't a setting in Xcode or a key for requiredDeviceCapabilities which allows you to make the app for iPhone 6+ only.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) there is no capability that isolates the iPhone 6 and 6+.
In this sense you can drop the idea of doing so because you would never pass AppStrore approval for what you are looking for. [added]Unable to use device capabilities[/added] The AppStore leaves you with only TWO device-specific options iPhone (for ALL iPhone models) and iPad (for ALL iPad models) or both.

For that to work without a specific capability the AppStore would need to change (!)

Sorry for bearing bad news :)

Comment: The app store does respect the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities plist entry - so you can specify e.g. that your app only works on devices with front-facing cameras, and it won't be shown on devices without one.

Comment: Then the link is the answer to your question! scroll down to the iPhone device capability table.

Comment: The closer you can get includes iPhone 5s, 6 and 6+. Two capabilities for that case "metal" and "opengles-3". No capability isolates iPhone 6+

Comment: Unfortunately, not being a solution, I believe this is the correct answer for your question.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer, the iPhone 6 and 6+ are not distinct devices they are still a part of the iPhone family.

Comment: The link's a good addition, but it's the same answer that Signo already gave, and the part about "The AppStore has only TWO device-specific options" is wrong because the app store supports capability checks.

Comment: The AppStore has only two device-specific options considering there's no chance to use DeviceCapabilities yes. But you can wait until new capabilities on future major os releases solves your problem instead of considering either answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well Signo is righgt.
iOS 8 supports devices with 3.5" & 4" screens, you can't use the only-support-iOS-x technique.

but yes you can do one more thing like for iphone6+, ipad you can continue with lots of screen space.and for other small screen devices you can design screen with required size by help of size class selection.

Hope it helps!!